# Separate data from text file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, text-files

I'm working on creating an analytics page that uses data stored in a text file. The text file is used for my highcharts graph and is separated like so:

```
November 7th 6AM,19.8
November 7th 6PM,19.8
November 8th 6AM,20.4
November 8th 6PM,14.6
November 9th 6AM,15.9
November 9th 6PM,15.1
November 10th 6AM,16.4
November 10th 6PM,16.4
```

I'm looking to separate that data into 12 calendar panes that will display overall discrepancies for each month. For example, if a date had the value 16, and then it dropped to 10 the next reading, to take a cumulative sum for how many times that happened for the month.

How do I make sure that it reads from the text file in proper order and that it checks to see if the next value went below 10 and tallies that somewhere?

Comment: "data into 12 calendar panes" - show how should look the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo can use jQuery to separate the file data into array.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //fetch text file
    $.get('text.txt', function(data) {
        //split on new lines
        var lines = data.split('\n');
        for(var i=0;i<lines.length;i++) {
            // use lines[i] the way you want
        }
    });
});
```

Then you can use this to get sub-strings:

```
var a = s.indexOf(',');
var b = s.substring(a,4);
```

This way you can separate the data and use it as desired.

Answer (score 0):

You need to

1. Fetch the data file

   - One usually does this with AJAX (XMLHttpRequest)
2. Separate your datapoints

   - Your data seems to be neat enough that you can, for every line in the file, get the name of the month with `line.split(" ")[0]` and the value with `line.split(",")[1]`. Splitting a text to lines can usually be as easy as `text.split("\n")`.
3. Iterate over results

   - For every month-value pair you now have, compare the name of the months. If it is a match and the value has changed by `x`, increment a value in your books, e.g. `discrepancies[monthName]++`. Save the name-value pair and continue.

Example:

```js
// Get the data
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) { // If the request is complete with status code "OK"
    handleImportantData(req.responseText);
  }
};
// Define the request to be using the method GET to an URL asynchronously.
req.open("GET", "important_data.txt", true);
req.send();

function handleImportantData(data) {
  var treshold = 5.0;
  var months = {};
  var discrepancies = {};

  // Separate data points.
  var lines = data.split("\n");
  lines.forEach(function(line) {
    // The || 0.0 part sets the value to zero if our data is malformed.
    // We parse the value as a float to prevent it being saved as a string,
    // which would make arithmetic operations on it not work as expected.
    months[line.split(" ")[0]] = parseFloat(line.split(",")[1]) || 0.0;
  });

  // Find discrepancies.
  var previous = {
    name: "",
    value: 0.0
  };
  for (var name in months) {
    // If not already there, initialize the data point with ternary operation including NOP.
    discrepancies[name] ? {} : discrepancies[name] = 0.0;

    // If we're still talking about the same month as before and the value
    // has changed for more than our treshold, save it as a discrepancy.
    if name === previous.name && Math.abs(previous.value - months[name]) > treshold {
      discrepancies[name] ++;
    }

    previous = {
      name: name,
      value: months[name]
    }; // Set this as the previous value.
  }

  // Here we have ready discrepancy data stored in the variable discrepancies.
}
```